# Excel pivot count to R code

Tags: r, excel

I'm working on below data and would like to replicate the [Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRJ1R.jpg) I did to R. I was able to do the sum and max but no idea how to do the count. Appreciate your help

```
Transaction Location    Invoice Paying_Party    Charge Delivery Paid    Points
123 UK  123_A   UK001   1   1   100
123 UK  123_B   UK001   1   0   100
123 UK  123_C   UK001   1   1   100
124 UK  124_A   UK001   1   1   100
124 UK  124_B   UK001   0   0   50
125 SE  125_A   SE005   0   0   50
126 HK  126_A   HK008   1   1   50
126 HK  126_B   HK008   1   1   50
127 DE  127_A   DE008   1   1   100
128 CN  128_A   CN002   0   1   150
128 CN  128_B   CN002   0   1   150
128 CN  128_C   CN002   0   0   150
128 CN  128_D   CN002   0   0   150
129 US  129_A   US007   1   1   100
129 US  129_B   US007   1   0   100
130 AU  130_A   AU111   1   0   150
130 AU  130_B   AU111   1   0   150
130 AU  130_C   AU111   1   1   150
```

Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
Summary<-setDT(Report)[, list(Points=max(Points),Charge.Delivery=max(Charge.Delivery),Paid=sum (Paid)),by=list(Transaction,Paying_Party,Location=as.factor(Location))]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Count = .N` like so:

`Summary<-DT[, list(Points = max(Points), 
                  Charge = max(Charge),
                  Paid   = sum (Paid),
                  Count  = .N),
                  by=list(Transaction,Paying_Party,Location=as.factor(Location))]`

I have `DT` as the `data.table` and `Charge` in place of `Charge.Delivery`.

Comment: Great! Thanks Sun Bee, really appreciate your quick response and help